# Replacing a multiple strings in a Pandas Series with values from a lookup table df

Tags: python, pandas, lookup, data-manipulation

I have a DataFrame like this, where the `type` column are strings delimited with `~`:

```
id | types    |
---------------
1  | A1~B1    |
2  | B1       |
3  | A1~A2~B2 |
```

I need to replace the strings in the 'type' column based on a lookup table, shown below, where both columns are strings. While doing this, I need to ensure that the final output has commas between the `types`.

```
type | description      |
------------------------
A1   | This is good     |
A2   | This is OK       |
B1   | This is not good |
B2   | This is bad      |
```

So the final output looks like this:

```
id | types                                 |
--------------------------------------------
1  | This is good, This is not good        |
2  | This is not good                      |
3  | This is good, This is OK, This is bad |
```

I've read that `.map()` is a good function to use, but I haven't been able to figure out how I can apply it to this scenario. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What were your attempts with `map`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of the above answers are using `apply`, which won't vectorize. I would suggest using `str.replace`:

```
string_map = {
    'A1': 'This is good',
    'A2': 'This is OK',
    'B1': 'This is not good',
    'B2': 'This is bad',
    '~': ', '
}
df = pd.DataFrame([{'type': 'A1~B1'}, {'type': 'B1'}, {'type': 'A1~A2~B2'}])
df_desc = df.copy()
for key, value in string_map.items():
    df_desc['type'] = df_desc['type'].str.replace(key, value)
```

Here, I'm assuming that the number of mappings in your mapping dictionary is much smaller than the number of rows in your DataFrame.

If you have your `string_map` in a DataFrame (call it `df_map`) as you've said, you can create a dictionary from it by running the following: `string_map = df_map.set_index('type')['description'].to_dict()`. Make sure you have `{type: '~', 'description': ', '}` as a row in your `df_map`.

Answer (score 2):

Let your first table be `df1` and the second `df2`.

I presume that type in the second dataframe takes the role of the index of the dataframe.

```
df1.map(lambda x: ','.join([df2[i] for i in x.split('~')]))
```

Answer (score 2):

A one-liner

```
df.types.str.replace('~', '|').agg(lambda k: df2.loc[df2.type.str.contains(k)].description.str.cat(sep=', ')
```

---

Explained:

You can use `replace` to replace `~` to `|`. That way, you get strings such as

```
A1|B1
```

which are easily searchable using `str.contains`, e.g.

```
df2.loc[df2.type.str.contains('A1|B1')]
```

returns

```
    type    description
0   A1  This is good
2   B1  This is not good
```

To concatenate these `description` values into `{}, {}` , just use `str.cat`. So the above gives

```
...description.str.cat(sep=', ')

'This is good, This is not good'
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `get_dummies`, then `replace`(rename) the columns  , then `dot`

```
newdf=df1['types'].str.get_dummies(sep='~').rename(columns=dict(zip(df2.type,df2.description+',')))
newdf.dot(newdf.columns)
Out[232]: 
id
1          This is good,This is not good,
2                           This is good,
3    This is good,This is OK,This is bad,
dtype: object
newdf.dot(newdf.columns).str[:-1]
Out[233]: 
id
1          This is good,This is not good
2                           This is good
3    This is good,This is OK,This is bad
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a series mapping `type` to `description`:

```
s = df_types.set_index('type')['description']
```

Then map your values via a list comprehension:

```
df['types'] = [', '.join(map(s.get, x.split('~'))) for x in df['types'].values]
```

`pd.Series.map` is also possible with similar logic, but may be less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`map` is indeed a way to do it, but there are a few steps to achieving the output you want. You can map on `lookup_table`, if it is a series with `type` as the index. First, though, you need to split on the delimiter `~`:

```
df['types'] = (df.types.str.split('~', expand=True)
               .apply(lambda x:
                      ', '.join(x.map(lookup_table
                                     .set_index('type')['description'])
                               .fillna('')), 1)
               .str.strip(', '))

>>> df
   id                                  types
0   1         This is good, This is not good
1   2                       This is not good
2   3  This is good, This is OK, This is bad
```